# VXLAN interface is not forwarding the packets to the ovs bridge

Tags: networking, openwrt, openflow, openvswitch

We are trying to mirror all the packets from an openflow supported router to a host and process the packet using ovs (openflow) in the host.

I have setup an environment which contains a ovs enabled router that mirrors all the traffic through vxlan to another host. In the host we have another ovs configured. We are receiving the packet sent from the router however the received packet is not being forwarded to the ovs-bridge.

We created a vxlan port in the host using this command:

[image]

We observed the RX traffic is incremented in the interface (shown below) however the packet is failed to forward to the ovs bridge.

[image]

What do you reckon is the best possible way to solve this issue?.